# ¿Como mostrar el texto de mi archivo en mi vista JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Hola amigos quiero mostrar el texto de mi archivo en mi vista(JSP) y tengo todo el codigo necesario hasta hago una prueba y si lo muestra por consola pero en mi pagina no, nose porque..

### Vista (JSP)

```
<form action="ControladorArchivos" method="get">

<input type="hidden" name="accion" value="lectorArchivo">

Especifique Ruta <input type="text" name="leerRuta"><br><br>

<input style="background-color: white; color: black; font-family: verdana; font-size:25px;" type="submit" value="Leer Archivo">
```

### Controlador(SERVLET)

```
  protected void LeemeArchivo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    EstadoRuta = request.getParameter("leerRuta");

    objetoArchivo = new ObjetoArchivos(EstadoRuta);

    modeloArchivo.LeerArchivo(objetoArchivo);

    ListaLeida = new ArrayList<String>();

    ListaLeida.add(objetoArchivo.miFrase);

    request.setAttribute("miFrase", ListaLeida);

    reenvio = request.getRequestDispatcher("ArchivosBienvenida.jsp");

    reenvio.forward(request, response);



}
```

### Modelo encargado de la lectura de mi archivo

```
public String LeerArchivo(ObjetoArchivos objetoArchivo) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    leerArchivo = new FileReader(objetoArchivo.getMiRuta());

    miBufer = new BufferedReader(leerArchivo);

    while(objetoArchivo.getMiFrase() != null) {

        objetoArchivo.miFrase = miBufer.readLine();

        if(objetoArchivo.getMiFrase() != null) {

            objetoArchivo.setMiFrase(objetoArchivo.miFrase);

            System.out.println(objetoArchivo.getMiFrase());

        }


    }


    return objetoArchivo.getMiFrase();
}
```

### Clase POJO

```
public class ObjetoArchivos {

    public String unionRyN, miRuta, miNombre, miTexto, EstadoArchivo, miFrase;

    public ObjetoArchivos(String miRuta) {

        super();

        this.miRuta = miRuta;


    }

    public ObjetoArchivos(String miRuta , String miNombre, String miTexto) {

        super();

        this.miRuta = miRuta;

        this.miNombre = miNombre;

        this.miTexto = miTexto;

        this.unionRyN = this.miRuta + this.miNombre;
    }

    public String getMiRuta() {
        return miRuta;
    }

    public void setMiRuta(String miRuta) {
        this.miRuta = miRuta;
    }

    public String getMiNombre() {
        return miNombre;
    }

    public void setMiNombre(String miNombre) {
        this.miNombre = miNombre;
    }

    public String getMiTexto() {
        return miTexto;
    }

    public void setMiTexto(String miTexto) {
        this.miTexto = miTexto;
    }


    public String getEstadoArchivo() {
        return EstadoArchivo;
    }

    public void setEstadoArchivo(String estadoArchivo) {
        EstadoArchivo = estadoArchivo;
    }



    public String getUnionRyN() {
        return unionRyN;
    }

    public void setUnionRyN(String unioRyN) {
        this.unionRyN = unioRyN;
    }



    public String getMiFrase() {
        return miFrase;
    }

    public void setMiFrase(String miFrase) {
        this.miFrase = miFrase;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjetoArchivos [miRuta=" + miRuta + ", miNombre=" + miNombre + ", miTexto=" + miTexto + "]";
    }





}
```

NOTA: No se porque no rescata el texto de mi archivo, a la hora de enviarlo a mi JSP, pero si me lo muestra en consola.

Comment: El JSP es puro HTML, no veo nada que intente mostrar ningún atributo que le hayas pasado

Comment: Tienes que leer teoría: http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Pasar_datos_entre_JSPs_y_Servlets._Page,_Request,_Session_y_Application_scope

Comment: Esos datos se envían a un Jsp principal llamado ArchivosBienvenida.jsp